# How to get value from vars of dir()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> a = 12
>>> dir()
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'a']
```

So it's everybody know!

But how we can get the value of a from dir()[-1]?

Comment: Use `globals()` and `locals()` to get the name and the value of a variable depending on the scope.

Comment: @Countour-Integral `locals()` should probably always work, since `locals() is globals()` when you call it in the global scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `exec` method.

```
a = 12
exec('b='+dir()[-1])
print(b)
>>> 12
```

the `exec` method executes the string inputs.

Comment: this generally will not work